# CreateWindow(): Type name is not allowed

Tags: c++, winapi

I am writing a C++ program in which I would like to create a window using the `CreateWindow()` function, but I cannot get it to work. I am unable to to compile the program, and the only information Visual Studio gives me in the Error List is "type name is not allowed." How can I resolve this? I haven't been able to determine how to fix it on my own. Here is the code for the program:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    int screenWidth = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
    int screenHeight = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);
    HWND window = CreateWindow("Melter", NULL, WS_POPUP, 0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight, HWND_DESKTOP, NULL, HINSTANCE, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't put `HINSTANCE` in here: `HWND window = CreateWindow("Melter",,..., HINSTANCE, NULL);` besides that, this code won't work. You need a `WinMain` entry, class name registration and message loop. Also Visual Studio can make a basic windows program, go to File->New->Project->C++->Win32->Win32 Project

Comment: @BarmakShemirani Would you mind posting an example of how to do it? I'm researching now and I cannot find something that I understand.

Comment: Did you see updated comment? Visual Studio can create a new Win32 Project automatically, including setting up resources and so on. Here are some links [Creating desktop window app](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384843.aspx) and you can google this term *"charles petzold programming windows 5th edition"*

Comment: @BarmakShemirani No, I did not see the edit. Thank you. I made the mistake of creating the project as a console application.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani: You don't *need* `WinMain`. You can get the HINSTANCE from `GetModuleHandle`.

Comment: `HINSTANCE` is a type (it's a handle to an instance). You need the actual application instance variable (which is usually provided via WinMain) instead for the call to CreateWindow. The documentation shows examples of properly using it; it probably wouldn't hurt to take a look at MSDN and read it.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani: "*You need a `WinMain` entry*" - no, you don't.  Console apps are still Win32 apps, and have full access to the Win32 API, and thus can create their own windows.

Comment: You need `WinMain` entry for a proper Windows program. `main` is for console programs, it can create windows but there would be an extra console window.

Answer (score 1):

To create a window from a console application you have saveral things to do.
First of all you have to register your own window class by `RegisterClass` with style paramters, a module handle
and most important a window procedure. The module handle you can get by `GetModuleHandle(0)`,
what returns a handle to the file used to create the calling process. The window procedure you have
to define yourslef. This is a function that processes messages sent to a window.
With this window class and the module handle you can create your window with `CreateWindow`.
After your window is created you have to show it with `ShowWindow`. Finally you need a message loop for your window:

```
#include <Windows.h>

// Window procedure which processes messages sent to the window
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure( HWND window, unsigned int msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp )
{
    switch(msg)
    {
        case WM_DESTROY: PostQuitMessage(0); return 0;
        default: return DefWindowProc( window, msg, wp, lp );
    }
}

int main()
{
    // Get module handle
    HMODULE hModule = GetModuleHandle( 0 );
    if (!hModule)
        return 0;

    // Register window class
    const char* const myWindow = "MyWindow" ;
    //const wchar_t* const myWindow = L"MyWindow"; // unicode
    WNDCLASS myWndClass = { 
        CS_DBLCLKS, WindowProcedure, 0, 0, hModule,
        LoadIcon(0,IDI_APPLICATION), LoadCursor(0,IDC_ARROW),
        CreateSolidBrush(COLOR_WINDOW+1), 0, myWindow };
    if ( !RegisterClass( &myWndClass ) )
        return 0;

    // Create window
    int screenWidth = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN)/2;
    int screenHeight = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN)/2;
    HWND window = CreateWindow( myWindow, NULL, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight, HWND_DESKTOP, NULL, hModule, NULL);
    if( !window )
        return 0;

    // Show window
    ShowWindow( window, SW_SHOWDEFAULT );

    // Message loop
    MSG msg ;
    while( GetMessage( &msg, 0, 0, 0 ) )
        DispatchMessage(&msg);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't include Winuser.h or Wingdi.h. Those are both automatically included by including Windows.h